# Calculate Mantel-Haenszel test in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, nonparametric

I would like to have a reality check of my understanding of the MH statistic.  I have been trying to reproduce an example of the Mantel-Haenszel test provided in Conover (1999, p. 192-194).  The data is structured as other examples provided for the procedure in R.

The statistic produces is the $T_{4}$ value, which is described as approximately normal when $H_{0}$ is true.  Conover describes $T_{4}$ as:

---

$$ T_{4} = \frac{\sum x_{i} - \sum{\frac{r_{i}\cdot c_{i}}{N_{i}}}}{\sqrt{\sum{\frac{r_{i}c_{i}(N_{i} - r_{i})(N_{i}- c_{i})} {N^2_{i} (N_{i}-1 )  }} }}    $$

---

The specification of the example on p. 194 is below:

```
cancer.in <- array(c(10,12,1,1,9,11,0,1,8,7,0,3), dim = c(2,2,3),
dimnames = list(status = c("treat", "control"), outcome  = c("success", "failure"),
group =  c("group-1", "group-2", "group-3")))

cancer <- as.table(cancer.in)

cancer

#####  continuity correction applied
mantelhaen.test(cancer)

#####  no correction applied
mantelhaen.test(cancer, correct = FALSE)
```

When examining the structure of the table, it seems to follow the example in the text, but the statistic provided does not match. Conover gets at $T_{4}$ value of $\frac{1.6786 }{1.1719} = 1.4323 $. The $\chi^{2}$ value that is returned in R is 2.0515 (without continuity correction), which equals the value $T_{4}^2$ .

From what I understand, $z^2$ is distributed $\chi^{2}_{1}$, so the methods are producing the same results, but represented in a different way.

Am I on the right track with this?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track. Not sure there's much more to say..?

Comment: @onestop Thanks so much!  If you want to post this as an answer, I'd definitely accept.